# OpenMVS , Windows compilation error

Tags: opencv, build, mvs

I've built 
 - Eigen3.2.10
 - OpenCV2.4.13
 - Ceres Solver 1.11.0
 - CGAL 4.9
 - Boost 1.62.0
 - VCG

The built all folders are in C:\develop . 
[image]

I opend cmd.exe and executed 
`git clone https://github.com/cdcseacave/openMVS.git src` at C:\develop .

next I executed 
`mkdir build`
`cd build`

and

`cmake . ../src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DEIGEN_DIR="../develop/eigen-3.2.10" -DOPENCV_DIR="../develop/opencv-2.4.13" -DCERES_DIR="../develop/ceres-solver-1.11.0" -DCGAL_DIR="../develop/cgal-4.9" -DVCG_DIR="../develop/vcglib-1.0.0"`

There were two errors 
・CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1793

・CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:106

[image]

What steps should I should take?

Comment: Consider copying the text from the prompt terminal and editing the question to include it, so that it can be read more easily and properly searched.

Answer (score 1):

Error states that CMake didn't find the packages required for build. It may be because CMake looks for them in other localization than they are or you may be running the script from wrong path.

If you are unsure the path provided is correct, try running the script with full paths, in example:

```
cmake . C:/src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DEIGEN_DIR="C:/develop/eigen-3.2.10" -DOPENCV_DIR="C:/develop/opencv-2.4.13" -DCERES_DIR="C:/develop/ceres-solver-1.11.0" -DCGAL_DIR="C:/develop/cgal-4.9" -DVCG_DIR="C:/develop/vcglib-1.0.0"
```

Please follow precisely the procedure described [in openMVS documentation](https://github.com/cdcseacave/openMVS/wiki/Building) for building the needed libraries and software for your operating system. Be sure to check if you have the correct packages versions listed in build dependencies.

I would also recommend you building this software on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. I successfully did the build on this operating system few day ago.